# Laravel: Eloquent select returning different results

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to understand how Eloquent select changes the results of a query. For example:

```
$startDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2023-01-26 00:00:00', 'America/Chicago')->timezone('UTC');
$endDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2023-01-26 23:59:59', 'America/Chicago')->timezone('UTC');
$data = Orders::where('canceled', 0)
    ->whereBetween('created_at', [$startDate->toDateTimeString(), $endDate->toDateTimeString()])
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('is_branding', 1)
            ->orWhere('is_premium_branding', 1);
        })
    ->get();
```

I have some other code running a foreach on this data to calculate and I end up with:

```
{
"branding_order_items_count": 12,
"branding_order_items_sales": 799.98,
"branding_order_items_margin": 169.71,
"branding_order_items_margin_percent": 0
}
```

However, if I run the same query but with an added select and calculate through the same foreach loop, I get a different result:

```
$startDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2023-01-26 00:00:00', 'America/Chicago')->timezone('UTC');
$endDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2023-01-26 23:59:59', 'America/Chicago')->timezone('UTC');
$data = Orders::where('canceled', 0)
    ->whereBetween('created_at', [$startDate->toDateTimeString(), $endDate->toDateTimeString()])
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('is_branding', 1)
            ->orWhere('is_premium_branding', 1);
        })
    ->select('*', DB::raw("count(*) as count")) // <<<<<<< Added this
    ->get();
```

With that added select, I get the following:

```
{
"branding_order_items_count": 11,
"branding_order_items_sales": 649.99,
"branding_order_items_margin": 142.12,
"branding_order_items_margin_percent": 0
}
```

The first result is the correct numbers, 12 items / 799.98, etc. So why does adding the select to the eloquent query return a different result, and how can I have it return the correct results while still using the select?

TIA

Comment: why do you add count without using any group by ? if you want to count the total data returned from `->get()` , what you can do is using `$count = count($data);`

Comment: @Win yep you're right, that's what I was missing!

Comment: extra note: you can use shorter code `$startDate = Carbon::parse('2023-01-26 00:00:00', 'America/Chicago')->tz('UTC')` and inside eloquent query ->whereBetween also accept Carbon, no need to convert it to DateTimeString. ... by the way be careful when search between 00:00:00 to 23:59:59, you might skip transaction happen exactly @ 23:59:59, best to do is `$current_tz = 'America/Chicago'; $server_tz = 'UTC'; $date = Carbon::parse('2023-01-26', $current_tz); $startDate = $date->tz($server_tz); $endDate = $date->addDay()->tz($server_tz);`

Comment: Also, Eloquent returns a collection, so `$data->count()` will also work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming this is using a MySQL database. PostgreSQL would throw a grouping error with that query.

The reason your results differ is most likely due to `DB::raw("count(*) as count")`. Without a `GROUP BY` clause, the results will only be 1 row of data.

If your `orders` table looks like this:

| id | cancelled |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 |

`SELECT * FROM orders WHERE cancelled = 0` will return

| id | cancelled |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |

`SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS count FROM orders WHERE cancelled = 0` will return

| id | cancelled | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 | 2 |

`SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS count FROM orders WHERE cancelled = 0 GROUP BY id` will return

| id | cancelled | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: Okay that makes perfect sense, and yea MySQL.. adding groupBy('id') fixed the issue I was running into! Thank you for the explanation!